# upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 fails at boot in virtualbox

Tags: boot, upgrade, virtualbox

Upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (upgrade manager) hang at boot (black screen) with cursor in virtualbox 5.2.16.
Worked fine from 14.04 to 16.04.at reboot (vbox command) i got the grub launcher. could not boot any of th 4.15.0 kernel. Selecting 4.4.0.131 is ok.
I tryed some tips found here but no luck.
In vmachine config, i changed "interface de paravirtualisation" (sorry, ican't xlate in english) from NONE to HYPER-V and now it boots fine ????????
HYPER-V is usually used by windows virtualisation system ???
Who can explains this ?
Rgds,
Chris2mop

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me upgrading from to 18.04 in VirtualBox 5.2.18. In my case I was able to fix it by powering off the VM, opening its settings in VirtualBox Manager, then:

System > Acceleration > Change *Paravirtualization Interface* from **Legacy** to **Default**. (Both hardware virtualization flags were already checked; I didn't need to change those).

Then I could boot into 18.04 ok - phew! I would've never have guessed this without your hint to look at the Paravirtualization Interface, so thanks!