# Boot fails after 16.04 LTS to 18.04 Bionic Beaver upgrade in Virtualbox on Windows 7 host

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 workstation and I use Virtualbox to run Ubuntu.  This is with UI not a headless deal.  I try to keep Virtualbox itself and all the Ubuntu packages up to date.  I have Virtualbox 5.2.18, currently the latest version available.  However my VM image was first created almost 4 years ago and regularly upgraded all this time, even through different Ubuntu dist upgrades.

Today I was offered a release upgrade **from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 Bionic Beaver**.  I saved a snapshot and proceeded with the upgrade.  Afterwards it reboots, and the VM never came up.  Kernel 4.10.0-32-generic is installed.  In normal mode, I just get a black screen with blinking cursor.  In recovery mode, the boot sequence freezes after this line:

> `x86: Booting SMP configuration:`

Because I have snapshots before and after the upgrade, I can easily switch and try things as I please.  During the upgrade, I was presented with the option to keep or remove dozens of packages that were declared unneeded, and I chose to remove them.

To be clear, the **VM configuration works just fine before the upgrade** to Bionic Beaver.  I'm left to assume that some kernel level change is responsible for the freeze.  But I'm not an expert on the kernel so I don't know what to try here.  These VM config options seem like they might be relevant:

- OS profile type = "Linux" and version = "Ubuntu (64-bit)"
- chipset = PIIX3
- I/O APIC is enabled
- EFI (special OS only) is disabled
- 2 CPUs in VM (host has 4) with PAE/NX enabled
- paravirtualization interface = "Legacy" (switching to "Default" or "KVM" does not seem to fix the issue by itself, though the 16.04 snapshot works fine with any of these options)
- VT-X is enabled
- nested paging is enabled
- 3d video acceleration is enabled

A user helpfully suggested that I boot from Live media within Virtualbox in order to capture logs to troubleshoot.  What exactly am I looking for and where?  Starting over with a clean install would be an inconvenience, costly in time.  (Running within Virtualbox was supposed to *prevent* this kind of OS decay.  *sigh*)

Comment: Can you reach the GRUB prompt?  If so, can you boot the system using an older kernel?

Comment: There is one older kernel defined in the bootloader.  It boots far enough to make it into init land, but X blows up.  I guess there is some dependency the new system has on the newer kernel version, or maybe some modules.

Comment: There is no such dependency. The easy solution is to boot from a Live image (iso), back up your data (data trapped in a snapshot is not easy to restore in this case), and then clean-install. Alternately, further troubleshooting requires access to /var/log/apt, which you can reach while booted from the Live image.

Comment: What am I looking for under /var/log/apt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After just waiting a while I was then offered an upgrade to **18.04.1** LTS, which does boot after upgrade.  (It still doesn't fully work, but that's a separate thing.)

Comment: How long is 'a while'? I gave up waiting but found an answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1073027/103266 (change the paravirtualization interface from Legacy to Default).

Comment: It was about a week before they patched the LTS.  No guarantee that will happen again, but hopefully they will consider Virtualbox a priority platform for supporting seamless release upgrades and fix my second issue too.